# Whenever cron jobs fail to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I'm trying to use the `whenever` gem to run cron jobs into my application. I want to recalculate the attribute "value" of my model "User" every two minutes. Here are the steps I took:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

**terminal**

```
$ bundle install
$ wheneverize .
```

**schedule.rb**

```
every 2.minutes do
  runner "User.recalculate"
end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
def self.recalculate
  User.all.each {|user| user.recalculate_value }
end

private

def recalculate_value
  self.value = self.value + 1
  self.save!
end
```

**terminal**

```
$ whenever --update-crontab
```

**and '$ whenever -l' returns this:**

```
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/website && bin/rails runner -e development '\''User:recalculate'\'''
```

But so far nothing has changed in my `User.values`. Running `User.recalculate` in my console works, so the error is apparently in Whenever. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide any logs or output to make question more clear?

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin Logs or output from where?

Comment: When you run whenever through crontab, it writes messages to syslog.
You also can try to run User.recalculate in rails console, just to check that code works well, and this is whenever issue.

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin Okay I knew I was missing something. What is syslog/where can I find it? User.recalculate works, so it's an issue with Whenever.

Comment: What OS do you have? I mean at what environment do you run whenever?
How exactly do you run it?

Comment: Well I have a Rails 4.0.10 app on an ubuntu machine, and I'm in development mode. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I quickly created a new Rails app to try to reproduce your problem, you can find it here, clone it and see for yourself.

https://github.com/mlainez/stackoverflow-28111330/blob/master/app/models/user.rb

First thing you will want to do is verify what environment the runner is running in. By default, whenever uses `production`. If you're on your local machine, be sure to set it to `development` in your schedule.rb or check the documentation to see how to update the crontab and set the correct environment.

https://github.com/mlainez/stackoverflow-28111330/blob/master/config/schedule.rb#L7

This is what you should see in your crontab:

```
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/marc/Projects/stack && bin/rails runner -e development '\''User.recalculate'\'''
```

Notice it says `rails runner -e development` and not `production`.

Another thing is that basia was right. When I leave the `private` keyword and try to execute `User.recalculate` in `rails c`, it fails with:

```
private method `recalculate_value' called for #<User ...>
```

I'm surprised it works with the private keyword in your console... You are trying to access a private method on an instance. This is not possible in Ruby. You can only access public methods of an instance from the outside (unless you use `send(:method)`).

Removing the private keyword fixed it and the task ran as expected every two minutes.

I'm using Rails 4.2.0 and ruby 2.1.0 in my github code.

**EDIT**

Make sure your cron daemon is running using:

```
service cron status
```

I also noticed that in your crontab output you have:

```
bin/rails runner -e development '\''User:recalculate'\''
```

Notice the `:` between `User` and `recalculate`. You must have made a typo in your schedule.rb

It should be a `.` as it's a method call.

Also, you might wanna check that the output from `whenever -l` and `crontab -l` are the same. If `crontab -l` is different or empty, then you didn't use `whenever --update-crontab` or `whenever -w` correctly or something might be wrong with the whenever version you're using.

Comment: Is there something I need to do to initialize cron or something? I changed the default environment to development, moved all the code out of the `private` section, and restarted the server, but it still isn't running the task. I updated the `$ whenever -l` output above.

Comment: Okay I knew I was missing something major. `$ service crond status` returns "crond: unrecognized service". How do I run a cron daemon?

Comment: That's odd. Then it's probably just `service cron status` without the 'd' at the end (I'm on OSX here sorry). Cron should be installed by default on Ubuntu. To start it or restart it use `service cron start` or `service cron restart`. You might have to do that with sudo.

Comment: Thank you! `sudo service cron start` finally did the trick: my cron job is finally running. Do you have any tips for running cron after I deploy onto a remote server?

Comment: cron should be running at startup by default on Ubuntu, I'm surprised it doesn't in your case, but I'm no Ubuntu expert... To add a service to default runlevels, use `sudo update-rc.d cron defaults` or `sudo update-rc.d cron enable` if it was disabled for some reason.

Comment: Something else I wanted to add is that you can see the cron log in `/var/log/syslog` & to visualize it in 'real time' you can use `tail -f /var/log/syslog`. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `private` since right now running `User.recalculate` will fail with `private method 'increment' called for #<User>` error.

BTW, is User an ActiveRecord class? Cause there is `increment` http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment method and `increment!` (saves record), so it might be good idea to change your method name to something else or just use `user.increment!(:value)`.

Comment: Yes, it's an ActiveRecord class. Thanks for the tip, I changed `increment` to `recalculate_value`.

Comment: I left `private` in, but running `User.recalculate` in the console works, so I don't think there are any issues in my `models/user.rb` code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be saving your user in your method `increment`. Try this:

```
def increment
  self.value = self.value + 1
  self.save
end
```

Comment: Oh, that's a mistake. I am saving in my original code: I updated the question.